# Функция не возвращает ответ Ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax

Всем привет. Помогите слепому разобраться, что я упустил.

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
 function getArrowsList(){
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/myPHP/action.php",
   data: {getMyArrows:'faster'}
  }).success: (function(data){
   if(data != '"err"' && data != ''){
    console.log(data); // тут логируется  ["left_down_Arrow.png", "up_arrow.png", "up_right_arrow.png"] все верно
    return data;
   }
  });
 }

 function getArrows(list){
  console.log(list); //тут пишет "undefined"
  for ( var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {//соответственно тут ошибка
      //
  }
 }
  getArrows(getArrowsList());
  });
```

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Ajax - от слова "асинхронный"

Comment: оно вообще распарсилось (`...}).success: (function(data){... `)?

Answer (score -1):

`getArrowsList() { $.ajax(...).success(); }` а где return?!

Comment: в данном случае return не поможет

Comment: getArrows(getArrowsList()); всё верно нету return - значит getArrows получит undefined.

Comment: а если добавишь return что получит getArrows? :-)

Comment: может имеет смысл написать `getArrowsList() { return $.ajax(....`, а потом вызывать отак: `getArrowsList().success(getArrows);`

Comment: Не, там же в succes еще проверка есть :-) а в getArrows - нету

Comment: ну добавить там `else return [];`

Comment: где именно _там_? :-)

Comment: там где if, else больше не куда притулять-то же ж!

Comment: @Zugr надо не "притулять", а разобраться, как оно работает

Comment: Саша я с вами не согласен, ибо это и есть ответ на его вопрос "что я упустил?", он return упустил... а следовательно неправильно использовал вызовы... ну и т.д. и .т.п. Главное зрим в корень... нет return